# 'unexpected error occurred Platform' - trying to use Conditional Expression with NotNull Operator

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to return a list of 'opps' where either of 2 fields has a value. So I thought I could simply use the 'NotNull conditional operator. However, this doesn't seem to work. The fields I'm checking are specified as a Guid field, but actually return a lookup. So basically, if it's not set to anything it's null, otherwise there's a lookup in there (not a specific value). I would have suspected that the NotNull operator would therefore still work but that doesn't seem to be the case. Here's my code:

```
public static BusinessEntityCollection GetOpps(string NewBU)
{
    ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();
    string oldBU1 = "";
    string oldBU2 = "";

    switch (NewBU)
    {
        case "NewBUA":
            oldBU1 = "field_Abuid";
            oldBU2 = "field_Bbuid";
            cols.Attributes = new string[] { "id", oldBU1, oldBU2 };
                break;
        case "NewBUB":
            oldBU1 = "field_Cbuid";
            oldBU2 = "field_Dbuid";
            cols.Attributes = new string[] { "id", oldBU1, oldBU2 };
            break;
    }

    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
    query.EntityName = "MyEntity";
    query.ColumnSet = cols;

    ConditionExpression ce = new ConditionExpression();
    ce.AttributeName = oldBU1;
    ce.Operator = ConditionOperator.NotNull;

    ConditionExpression ce2 = new ConditionExpression();
    ce2.AttributeName = oldBU2;
    ce2.Operator = ConditionOperator.NotNull;

    FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
    filter.Conditions = new ConditionExpression[] { ce, ce2 };
    filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;

    query.Criteria = filter;

    BusinessEntityCollection MyCollection = new BusinessEntityCollection();

    try
    {
        using (crmService)
        {
            MyCollection = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        }
    }
    catch (SoapException se)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error occurred retrieving opps for " + NewBU + ". " + se.Detail.InnerXml);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error occurred retrieving opps for " + NewBU + ". " + ex.Message);
    }

    return MyCollection;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is down to the 2 conditional expressions as I've removed them and simply returned a specific opp based on a guid and it worked (and displayed a lookup in 1 of the specified fields). So, if my assumption is correct as to why I'm getting the error how can I check the fields and return opps where either of those fields is not null?

Comment: Field and entity names must be specified in lower case; custom entities and fields should be specified with their prefix. If this does not solve your problem, simplify your code to the absolute minimum and try again. For further help, share the exception details with us.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen - thanks for the suggestion. My field and entity names are actually in lower case, but in this example I'm not using the real names and forgot that rule. I think I may try and go about it another way of returning the lookup first and then using the guid.